# method reference expected error on multiple filter in lambda java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to use 2 conditions in the filter but giving an error

```
ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("OWVjZWU2");
    add("YWVjZWU2");
    add("ZWVjZWU2");
}};
mypairs.stream().filter(pair -> abc.contains("ded") || Utils::mymethod).collect(..some code..)
```

But this condition is working fine

```
mypairs.stream().filter(Utils::mymethod).collect(..some code..)
```

P.S `mymethod` is the method like:

```
public static boolean isPacingExcluded(ABSType pair)
```

I am new to java and checking what is going wrong here

Comment: `Utils::mymethod` represent a `Predicate`, but `pair -> abc.contains("ded") || Utils::mymethod` does not. you can use `pair -> abc.contains("ded") || Utils.myMethod(pair)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a method reference along with a lambda expression, so you need to use
`pair -> abc.contains("ded") || Utils.isPacingExcluded(pair)`.

Also, from the code it looks like `abc.contains("ded")` is not related to any element of `mypairs`. i.e the result of `abc.contains("ded")` is independent of the elements of `mypairs` and hence you need not repeat that for each element of the list. I would suggest that the code be changed as:

```java
if(abc.contains("ded")) {
    mypairs.stream().filter(Utils::mymethod).collect(..some code..)
}
```